# SQL Server Connection is getting closed after its idle for certain amount of time

Tags: sql-server, azure, spring-boot

I have deployed my spring boot application in Azure and it's communicating with the SQL server database running in Azure. I am able to hit the rest endpoint and getting the JSON data back. But when the application is idle for some time and them i'm trying to hit the same rest endpoint I am getting the following error.

**error**

```
 org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.] with root cause.
```

Here is my **application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:sql_server
  application:
    name: facilitiesmanagement
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
liquibase:
  change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

spring:
  profiles: sql_server
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://testserver.database.windows.net;databaseName=test
    username: hello
    password: passw@ord
    initialize: true
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    dbcp2:
      initial-size: 10
      max-total: 25
      pool-prepared-statements: true
    jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
      database: sql_server
```

Can someone please help me how to make the connection running all the time without getting closed.Do i need to add any  additional properties in order to achieve that?

I am using 6.1.0.jre8 version and basic tier plan

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server are you running? Are you running a SQL Server in a Azure VM or you are running a managed Azure SQL Database?

Comment: version is 6.1.0.jre8. I am running a managed azure sql database

Comment: What is the Azure database service tier you are using? You should give more specific details in order for others to provide a more useful answer which could help you

Comment: I apologize for not providing the enough details. I am using Basic tier

Comment: Hmm, it could be just a transient error. Connection errors to Azure SQL happen sometimes. Usually retrying after 1 second helps. Not sure how your ORM here is configured for retries :)